# Show multiple table data in View ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two table which is connected by ID. One table is for specialty medical provider, the second one is the list of the medical provider. I want to display SpecialityName in View

[image: ListOfSpeciality]

[image: Table of Medical Providers]

[image: View]

SO far I create a controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public virtual JsonResult MedicalInput(int id)
        {

            var medProvidersInput = db.Contacts.Where(s => s.Id == id && s.ContactCategory.Name == "Facility").Select(a => new
            {
                Id = a.Id,
                Firstname = a.Firstname,
                Address1 = a.Address1,
                TypeId = a.TypeId,
                City = a.City,
                State = a.State,
                Zip = a.Zip,
                Mobile = a.Mobile,

            });

            //ViewData["medProvidersInput"] = medProvidersInput;
            return Json(medProvidersInput, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

The second part of the code I create in the script for fetching these elements to View and display in TextView (Picture 3)

```
$(document).on('click', '.sortList', function () {

        var selectLat = $(this).closest("tr").attr('data-lat');
        var selectLong = $(this).closest("tr").attr('data-long');



        $('.sortList').each(function () {
            $(this).closest("tr").removeClass('success');
        });


        $(this).closest("tr").addClass('success');


        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $.getJSON("/NfDocuments/MedicalInput", { id: id },
           function (data) {

              $('#medInput').empty();

               $.each(data, function () {
                   // $("#medInput").append("'" + this.Id + "'");
                   //console.log(this.Id);
                   var medInput = document.getElementById("medInput");
                   medInput.value = this.Firstname + ' - '
                                  + this.Zip + ' '
                                  + this.Address1 + ','
                                  //+ this.TypeId + ','
                                  + this.City + ','
                                  + this.State + ' - '
                                  + this.Mobile;
               });

           });
```

SO I want to select Name from table and display in TextView after Address field.
So my question is: Is it possible to convert ID to String, that I can get specialty name in textview?? 
Thank you

Comment: are those real phone numbers and addresses you've posted up here on the public internet? Was that really necessary for your question? Maybe those companies make some of that info public anyway, but I'd guess maybe the mobile numbers are not, perhaps

Comment: Anyway... "I want to display SpecialityName in View"...which database table is this in? If there's a relationship between that table and your Contacts table, since you're using EF you should just be able to include that field in your .Select() call e.g. `Mobile = a.Mobile, SpecialtyName = a.SomeTable.Name` or whatever. Then it'll be in your JSON, and then you can display it

Comment: Of course, the Phone numbers are not real, it's fake. I just take it to test the application

Comment: Ok, just checking! Sometimes people forget. They _look_ real enough, that's all.

Comment: Yes, thes two table are in realationship, as you can see from picture. I use TypeID from ContactType table.

Comment: @ADyson When I type SpecialtyName = a.SomeTable.Name it display Table and field, so just I need to display it in View

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173804/discussion-between-joe123-and-adyson).

Comment: Thank you @ADyson :) It works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Entity Framework, and there's a relationship between your tables already, tou can include the field in your .Select() statement very easily:

```
var medProvidersInput = db.Contacts.Where(s => s.Id == id && s.ContactCategory.Name == "Facility").Select(a => new
            {
                Id = a.Id,
                Firstname = a.Firstname,
                Address1 = a.Address1,
                TypeId = a.TypeId,
                City = a.City,
                State = a.State,
                Zip = a.Zip,
                Mobile = a.Mobile,
                SpecialtyName = a.ContactType.Name //make a field called SpecialtyName using the contact type name field
            });
```

This will then automatically be included in your JSON, and in your JavaScript code you can use it and display it however you need to.

Comment: Thank you @ADyson